# Pixel3 ACTION_VIEW won't start for other files than images

Tags: android, image, android-intent, mime-types, android-intent-chooser

This is my code for trying to open a file I create from a base64 string:

```
var decodedBytes = Base64.decode(filtered.first().contentsB64String, Base64.NO_WRAP)
var ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(commonName)
fileTemporary = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/xelion/xelion_temp." + ext)
if (fileTemporary != null) {
    if (!fileTemporary!!.exists()) {
        fileTemporary?.createNewFile()
    }
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(fileTemporary, decodedBytes)
    var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    var uri = Uri.fromFile(fileTemporary)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        uri = Uri.parse(fileTemporary!!.getPath())
    }
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, filtered.first().mimeType)
    activity!!.startActivity(intent)
}
```

I have also tried with this , but I still get the same error:

```
    fun openFile(url: Uri) {
        var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        if (url.toString().contains(".doc") || url.toString().contains(".docx")) {
            // Word document
            intent.setDataAndType(url, "application/msword")
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".pdf")) {
            // PDF file
            intent.setDataAndType(url, "application/pdf")
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".ppt") || url.toString().contains(".pptx")) {
            // Powerpoint file
            intent.setDataAndType(url, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".xls") || url.toString().contains(".xlsx")) {
            // Excel file
            intent.setDataAndType(url, "application/vnd.ms-excel")
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".zip") || url.toString().contains(".rar")) {
            // WAV audio file
            intent.setDataAndType(url, "application/x-wav")
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".rtf")) {
            // RTF file
            intent.setDataAndType(url, "application/rtf")
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".wav") || url.toString().contains(".mp3")) {
            // WAV audio file
            intent.setDataAndType(url, "audio/x-wav")
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".gif")) {
            // GIF file
            intent.setDataAndType(url, "image/gif")
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".jpg") || url.toString().contains(".jpeg") || url.toString().contains(".png")) {
            // JPG file
            intent.setDataAndType(url, "image/jpeg")
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".txt")) {
            // Text file
            intent.setDataAndType(url, "text/plain")
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".3gp") || url.toString().contains(".mpg") || url.toString().contains(".mpeg") || url.toString().contains(".mpe") || url.toString().contains(".mp4") || url.toString().contains(".avi")) {
            // Video files
            intent.setDataAndType(url, "video/*")
        } else {
            //if you want you can also define the intent type for any other file
            //additionally use else clause below, to manage other unknown extensions
            //in this case, Android will show all applications installed on the device
            //so you can choose which application to use
            intent.setDataAndType(url, "*/*")
        }

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        activity!!.startActivity(intent)

    }
```

Error:

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/xelion/xelion_temp.txt typ=text/plain flg=0x10000001 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `/storage/emulated/0/xelion/xelion_temp.txt` is not a valid `Uri`. [Use `FileProvider` to make your content available to other apps.](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider)

Second, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is inaccessible to you on Android 10 (by default) and Android R+ (for all apps). When you switch to using `FileProvider`, you will be able to switch to storing this data in `getCacheDir()` or similar locations supplied by `Context`.

Also, your second code snippet has bugs:

- It will think that `this.is.not.a.ppt.txt` is a PowerPoint presentation
- It uses wildcard MIME types, which are not meant for use by *suppliers* of content

And, bear in mind that there is no requirement for every Android device to have apps that support every possible content type.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I handled with a popup if it cannot open. I will look into the FileProvider now, and come back with more info after. thanks